# How to update the value in dictionary as child tree in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I wang to create a data storage as the reference of firebase, and using the dictionary. But the value can not be update into the child of dictionary.

```
var test:[String: Any?] = ["c1": ["c2": ["c3": 5]]]

class JSON {
    var dict:[String: Any?]
    
    init( _ val:inout [String: Any?]) {
        dict = val
    }
    
    func child(key: String) -> JSON {
        var json = dict[key] as! [String: Any?]
        return JSON(&json)
    }
    
    func setValue(key:String, value:Any?) {
        dict[key] = value
    }
    
    func getInteger(key:String) ->Int {
        return dict[key] as! Int
    }
}

var json = JSON(&test)

// Update c3 = 27
json.child(key: "c1").child(key: "c2").setValue(key: "c3", value: 27)

print("JSON: \(json.child(key: "c1").child(key: "c2").getInteger(key: "c3"))")
// But c3 = 5
```

Comment: Long story short: It's not possible. `var json = dict[key] as! [String: Any?]` returns a copy of the dictionary regardless of the `inout` annotation. By the way `[String:Any?]` makes not sense. According to the definition the key is missing if `nil` is returned.

Comment: @vadian not only that but `inout` is only "effective" until the called function returns.  Just because `dict` is passed to the `init` as `inout` doesn't make it update during subsequent function calls that modify `JSON.dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vadian says, the fundamental problem is that dictionaries are value types. Any time you do an assignment, of a dictionary, a new copy is made (not strictly true, but to all intents and purposes, it might as well be). Even in your initialiser with the `inout` parameter

```
    init( _ val:inout [String: Any?]) {
        dict = val
    }
```

You can modify `val` and the change will be reflected in the passed in variable, but `dict` is a copy of `val`: modifying it won't change `val`.

To solve your problem, assuming this is the API you want, the class `JSON` has to encapsulate the hierarchy in itself. i.e. the sub dictionaries should be instances of `JSON`. `JSON` is a reference type so changes in instances passed as parameters will be reflected in the caller.

Here's a rough outline of one way to implement your API.

```
class JSON {
    enum Node
    {
        case leaf(Any)
        case subTree(JSON)
    }

    var dict:[String: Node] = [:]

    init( _ val: [String: Any])
    {
        for (key, value) in val
        {
            if let valueAsDict = value as? Dictionary<String, Any>
            {
                dict[key] = .subTree(JSON(valueAsDict))
            }
            else
            {
                dict[key] = .leaf(value)
            }
        }
    }

    func child(key: String) -> JSON {
        let value = dict[key]! // Will crash if empty. Needs to be more graceful
        switch value
        {
        case .leaf(_):
            fatalError("Do something more graceful")
        case .subTree(let json):
            return json
        }
    }

    func setValue(key:String, value:Any) {
        dict[key] = .leaf(value)
    }

    func getInteger(key:String) ->Int {
        let value = dict[key]! // Will crash if empty. Needs to be more graceful
        switch value
        {
        case .leaf(let ret):
            return ret as! Int // May crash
        case .subTree(_):
            fatalError("Do something more graceful")
        }
    }
}

var test:[String: Any] = ["c1": ["c2": ["c3": 5]]]
var json = JSON(test)

// Update c3 = 27
json.child(key: "c1").child(key: "c2").setValue(key: "c3", value: 27)

print("JSON: \(json.child(key: "c1").child(key: "c2").getInteger(key: "c3"))")
//  prints "JSON: 27"
```

Comment: I still don't understand why your dictionary + Node can keep the value ...

Comment: @rhino because `JSON` is a class. It has reference semantics, not copy semantics. With a `struct` (`Dictionary` is a `struct`) every time you do an assignment or pass it as a parameter, you get a new copy of the whole thing. Changes made in the copy are not reflected in the original.

Comment: @rhino With a class, when you do an assignment or pass it as a parameter, you are passing a reference (a pointer) to the original instance.

Comment: @rhino So each instance of `JSON` has a dictionary providing its storage and it's not copied around, it's just changed when you call `setValue(...)`

Comment: Probably should have put all of that in the answer.